# How to add specific amount of gaussian or salt & pepper noise using matlab function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

This question could be very silly for others, but for me it is very difficult.

Hello, I am a beginner in **MATLAB**, I am recently reading a paper where we have to add noise in an image in following manner.

Gaussian Noise => **sigma** = 10

Salt & Pepper Noise => **p** = 20% **sp**

I know about **MATLAB** functions for adding noise, we use `imnoise()` function for it.

```
noise_image = imnoise(input_image, 'salt & pepper', gaus_val)
```

will add salt & pepper noise and

```
noise_image = imnoise(input_image, 'gaussian', 0 , salt_pepper_val);
```

will add ZERO-MEAN Gaussian noise of variance `salt_pepper_val`.

**Now my question is that using imnoise() function how can I add following amount of noise. In other words for what value of gaus_val and salt_pepper_val, I will get gaussian noise of amount  sigma = 10%, 20%,..... and salt and pepper noise of amount 20%, 30%...............**

Gaussian Noise => **sigma** = 10

Salt & Pepper Noise => **p** = 20% **sp**

Comment: down voters or people who will wish to close this question, kindly dare to put your comments, it a difficult one for me hopefully not for you.

Comment: `variance = sigma^2`, other then that, I think you answered your own question... If your problem is how to add both, you can just add one and then the other, just feed `noise_image` to the second `imnoise`

Comment: Despite the edit, I still don't understand your question. You ask for a method to implement some noise, you want it to be `imnoise`, then you provide the relevant code that answers your own question. You may want to formulate your question again, or be more specific to get an answer.

Comment: now you removed your own attempts completely, wouldn't it had been better to tell us what was wrong with them?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "add 20% of Gaussian noise"? What is wrong with the results obtained by your current implementation? What are you expecting instead of these results?

Comment: Variance, or std, are (squared) units of the variable. Presuming "10%" noise means 10% relative to the baseline of the image then:

// Use this definition of SNR:
SNR = mu/std; 
ns = 0.1*mean(mean(noise_image);
noise_image = noise_image + normrnd(0,ns,size(noise_image));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different parameters are used because the two types of noise are characterised differently:

1. gaussian noise corrupts the whole image, and if it's white (i.e. no spatial covariance) with zero mean (on average it doesn't brighten or darken the image) then it is completely defined by the noise amplitude sigma. if you read the documentation www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html then you see that you can specify both the mean and the variance (sigma*sigma -- if sigma = 10 then variance = 100). you can then add noise with sigma 10 using:

   ```
   >> noise_image = imnoise(input_image, 'gaussian', 0 , 100);
   ```
2. salt and pepper noise are white(salt) and black(pepper) spots in an image, i.e. they don't affect every pixel. sp is the percentage of an image that is corrupted (default 5% or 0.05), so sp = 20% = 0.2 means that 1 in 5 pixels are corrupted:

   ```
   >> noise_image = imnoise(input_image, 'salt & pepper', 0.2);
   ```

exactly as described on the help page.

EDIT: please beware that `imnoise()` is used for images with intensities between 0 and 1, and that values outside the range [0,1] are clipped -- the variance may not be the one you specify.

you can also easily do the same without using imnoise:

*(1)* load an image as [0,1] greyscale:

```
  >> input_image = mean(imread('peppers.png'),3)/256;
```

*(2)* add gaussian noise of 0.1 * the image's sigma:

```
  >> image2 = randn(size(input_image)); 
  >> image2 = input_image+image2*0.1*std(input_image(:))/std(image2(:));
```

*(3)* add s&p noise in 20% of pixels:

```
  >> image3 = input_image; 
  >> li=randperm(length(image3(:))); 
  >> image3(li(1:(end/5)))=1; 
  >> image3(li(1:(end/10)))=0;
```

*(4)* show side by side:

```
  >> imagesc([input_image image2 image3])
```